# Can cross entropy loss be used to compare how well a model performs on different parts of a dataset?

Tags: classification, probability, cross-entropy, information-theory

Say that I have a dataset with binary labels and a binary classification model. I then split the dataset into N parts. Now if I measure the cross-entropy loss on each split, will the resulting cross-entropies become objective measures of how well the model can predict each part regardless of the labels or data in each split?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you mean by split. If you are assigning data to different categories based on the input variables, e.g. put all the examples for x > 10 in one category and all the ones for which x <= 10 into another category, then you are creating what's called a hierarchical model, and there is lots of work on models of that kind, which a web search should find. Followups to stats.stackexchange.com; this is actually off topic here.

Comment: @RobertDodier So the idea is not to create a model based on these splits, just to evaluate an already trained model and determine where it performs well or not.

Comment: Totally makes sense to me. I wouldn't be surprised if you find the model is pretty accurate in some parts of the input space and not so much in others, which then leads to the question of how to improve accuracy over here while not spoiling it over there. Good luck and have fun, it's a good problem.

Comment: @RobertDodier Great. Yes, that's my hypothesis also. Thank you.